# Как добавить событие?

Tags: c#, события, wpf

Кто знает, как добавить `SelectionChaged` к комбобоксу такого вида?

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding ="{Binding name_ru}" CellStyle="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle}" x:Name="stcombo"  Header="Статус" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать так

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle">
        <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="MyEvent"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="ComboBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}">                
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: пишет
TargetType "ComboBox" не соответствует типу элемента "DataGridCell". не знаешь что это?

Comment: Возможно, я на данных не тестировал
В гугле нашел такое решение
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000020/is-it-possible-to-exposed-the-datagridcomboboxcolumn-immediately